# index events on mouse click tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to index multiple clicks on a Tkinter canvas?  I am trying to write a Python script that will save four unique user-selected regions of an image.  Each image has text overlaid on it showing latitude, longitude, date and time.  The goal is to have the user select the four regions with that text and crop them to create four new images.
The script works so far and has a user open an image, draw rectangles, and print the coordinates of the rectangles.  When I have the coordinates saved to a variable, it is overwritten by the next rectangle.
How can I index the rectangle selections (or events) so lat, lon, date and time can have unique variables that can be passed to another function to crop those parts of the image?
Here is the script (question is in comments near end):

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import os

class kanvas(Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.canv = Canvas(self, width = 720, height = 480, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.hScroll = Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal',
                             command=self.canv.xview)
        self.hScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self.vScroll = Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical',
                             command=self.canv.yview)
        self.vScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self.canv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=4, pady=4)        
        self.canv.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hScroll.set,
                        yscrollcommand=self.vScroll.set)

class ImgTk(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
    #This function asks the user to select an image then opens it on a tkinter window
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        #Above line calls the super class's '__init__' method; resolved error of 'get attr'
        button = tkMessageBox.showinfo(message = "Draw rectangles around lat, lon, date and time")

        self.main = kanvas(self)
        self.main.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
        self.c = self.main.canv

        self.currentImage = {}
        self.load_imgfile(askopenfilename(parent = tk.Toplevel(), initialdir = "D:/", title = "Choose an image:"))

        self.c.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_mouse_down)
        self.c.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.on_mouse_drag)
        self.c.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.on_mouse_up)

    def load_imgfile(self, filename):
        self.img = Image.open(filename)
        self.currentImage['data'] = self.img

        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.c.xview_moveto(0)
        self.c.yview_moveto(0)
        self.c.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor='nw', tags='img')
        self.c.config(scrollregion=self.c.bbox('all'))
        self.currentImage['photo'] = self.photo


    def on_mouse_down(self, event):        
        self.anchor = (event.widget.canvasx(event.x),
                   event.widget.canvasy(event.y))
        self.item = None

    def on_mouse_drag(self, event):        
        bbox = self.anchor + (event.widget.canvasx(event.x),
                          event.widget.canvasy(event.y))
        if self.item is None:
            self.item = event.widget.create_rectangle(bbox, outline="red")
        else:
            event.widget.coords(self.item, *bbox)

    def on_mouse_up(self, event):        
        if self.item:
            self.on_mouse_drag(event) 
            box = tuple((int(round(v)) for v in event.widget.coords(self.item)))
            roi = self.currentImage['data'].crop(box) # region of interest
            values = roi.getdata() # pixel values
            coords = [roi.size[0], roi.size[1], box[0], box[1]]
            print coords

        # Main question: how do I save unique variables from events?
        # The following is what I would like to be able to do:
        # lat = coords from event[0]
        # lon = coords from event[1]
        # time = coords from event[2]
        # date = coords from event[3]

app = ImgTk()
app.mainloop()
```

[Here is an example image (rectangle selections in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSpZG.png).

I'm relatively new to to Python, so please forgive any newbie syntax mistakes.  Thank you for your help!

**EDIT**  I figured out a solution, in case anyone else comes across this.  Create a global list (crop_regions), then append it within the last function.

```
import...
cro_regions = []
class kanvas(...):
...
class ImgTk(...):
    def __init__(...)
    ...
    def on_mouse_up(...)
        if self.item:
            self.on_mouse_drag(event) 
            box = tuple((int(round(v)) for v in event.widget.coords(self.item)))
            roi = self.currentImage['data'].crop(box) # region of interest
            values = roi.getdata() # pixel values
            coords = [roi.size[0], roi.size[1], box[0], box[1]]
            lat =  roi.size[0],'x',roi.size[1],'+',box[0],'+',box[1]
            lat = str(lat)
            lat = lat.replace(',','')
            lat = lat.replace("'", '')
            lat = lat.replace(' ','')
            global crop_regions
            crop_regions.append(lat)

app = ImgTk()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I do not understand the question.  How does selecting a rectangle create 4 images instead of 1 and what does "one each for latitude, longitude, date and time." mean?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I just edited my post to hopefully make it more clear.  Basically, I want to select a region where latitude is written, longitude, etc... and save the coordinates of each of those rectangles.